# Как использовать несколько view в RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-view, recyclerview

Мне нужно в зависимости от типа объекта(записи), заполнить `RecyclerView` разными `view`, раньше когда я делал это с помощью `ListView` у меня получалось, а тут я даже не знаю как это организовать, в `onCreateViewHolder` сразу создается `view` но без учета текущей позиции, следовательно я не могу несколько разных `view` там создать.

Как это можно организовать?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Для создания айтемов разного вида необходимо переопределить метод адаптера `getItemViewType()`, который будет в зависимости от условия определять, айтем какого вида требуется в данной позиции. В `RecyclerView` этот механизм был улучшен и метод `onCreateViewHolder()` возвращает значение `ViewType` - какой тип айтема требуется в данной позиции:

```
class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <MyAdapter.ItemHolder> {

    private final int TYPE_ITEM1 = 0;
    private final int TYPE_ITEM2 = 1;

    public MyAdapter () {
     // конструктор адаптера
    }

    @Override
    public ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v;

        switch (viewType) {
         // инфлейтим нужную разметку в зависимости от того,
         // какой тип айтема нужен в данной позиции

            case TYPE_ITEM1:
                v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item1, parent, false);
                break;
            case TYPE_ITEM2:
                v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item2, parent, false);
        }
      return new ItemHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder( ItemHolder holder, int position) {

     // Получаем тип айтема в данной позиции для заполнения его данными
        int type = getItemViewType(position);

        switch (type) {
            case TYPE_ITEM1:
                holder.mText1.setText("биндим данные в айтем типа 1");
                break;  
            case TYPE_ITEM2:
                holder.mText2.setText("биндим данные в айтем типа 2");
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
         // условие для определения айтем какого типа выводить в конкретной позиции
        if (position == <условие>) return TYPE_ITEM1;
        return TYPE_ITEM2;
    }

public static class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView mText1;
    TextView mText2;

    public ItemHolder(View v) {
        super(v);

        mText1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        mText2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text2);
    }
 }
```

Comment: А есть возможность использовать разные Holder'ы что бы не сваливать все в один?

Comment: @wpbloger Вы можете использовать любое нужное вам количество холдеров и прочие оптимизации и паттерны. Это лишь минимальный пример, основная цель которого - принцип использования метода `getItemViewType()`

Comment: @wpbloger Смотрите, скажем, [этот пример](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView)

Comment: А что если я получаю данные списками?
Поясню:
    private List<TextNumeric> android;

    public DataAdapter(List<TextNumeric> android) {
        this.android = android;
    }
Только сейчас уже получаю не один тип, а два, как в Вашем примере. Подскажите как возможно подкорректировать пожалуйста.

Comment: Мда, неудобно, что разработчики сделали возвращаемое значение типа `int`...

Answer (score 2):

Можно писать свой адаптер, как ответил @pavlofff, можно воспользоваться готовыми библиотеками: 
https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter
https://github.com/sockeqwe/AdapterDelegates

Answer (score 1):

У кого остались вопросы по примеру, приведённому выше, (или кто-то хочет более детально разобраться), в дополнение к примеру [ссылку](http://alexzh.com/tutorials/multiple-row-layouts-using-recyclerview/) Вам!

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/105800)

Comment: скинул ссылку где более подробно освящается вопрос(мне помогло, решил поделиться).