# Как в ListView вывести TextView, после N-ого элемента CardView

Tags: android, listview

Есть список, построенный на `cardView`. Каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы после каждой, к примеру, 20 записи, вставлялся какой-либо `view` (пусть это будет `textView`), а после него уже дальше продолжался список.

Какая реализация возможна? Не сталкивался с этим, но представляю себе это так:
* в `layout` файле макета `cardview`, дописать помимо самого `cardview` еще этот самый `textView` и сделать его невидимым. А после, на проверке в адаптере, делать видимым в зависимости от такого, какой сейчас по счету `item` в списке идет.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/470214/177345 - не надо ничего представлять и выдумывать - для вашей задачи есть типовое решение, заложенное в класс `ListView` изначально. Нужно переопределить метод `getItemViewType()`, который определяет айтем какого вида требуется в текущей позиции. Гайд по ссылке для `RecyclerView`, но для `ListView` почти то же самое.

Comment: @pavlofff, да, так можно, но, в отличие от предложенного в вопросе, возникает надобность, как мне кажется, в постоянном учёте этих вставленных элементов при определении из какой позиции брать данные для "обычных" элементов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно в методе `getItemViewType()` адаптера в зависимости от текущей позиции указывать другой тип элемента:

```
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_CARDVIEW = 0;
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_TEXTVIEW = 0;

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position % 20 == 0 ? VIEW_TYPE_TEXTVIEW : VIEW_TYPE_CARDVIEW;
}
```

И в зависимости от текущего типа элемента в методе `getView()` отдавать `TextView` либо `CardView`