# Несколько RecyclerView на одном экране

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Добрый день. Стоит задача сделать экран, в котором будет несколько Recycler View. В каждом RecyclerView будет несколько Card View. Как это правильно реализовать? Для каждого Recycler View создавать контейнер? Вот примерный рисунок, как должно выглядеть:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
эскиз [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что мешает засунуть это всё в один RecyclerView?

Comment: Если это для выбора каких то пунктов по нескольким отдельным параметрам, то уместнее будет использовать `Spiner`, при вашей компоновке в каждом списке будет видно в лучшем случае полтора элемента, если речь идет о телефонах.

Comment: @xkor нужно именно несколько RecyclerView, а между ними text view

Comment: @Denis422 почему нужно именно так? Что не позволяет использовать один RecyclerView? Религия? Или они у вас отдельно друг от друга скролятся? Отдельные действительно логичны только в этом случае.

Comment: @xkor хорошо, если использовать 1 RecyclerView (дабы не засорять код и т.д.), то как реализовать:  экран, скролящийся вниз в зависимости от количества элементов; на экране текствьюшка, сразу за ней следует список RecyclerView из CardView; Далее новая текствьюшка, за ней опять следует RecyclerView; Количество CardView в каждом списке может быть разное, но оно известно до перехода на этот экран. Подскажите как правильно это реализовать, возможно мой план изначально был неверен.

Answer (score 5):

На сколько я понимаю у вас 3 списка разных типов элементов и заголовки между ними. Такая структура легко организуется на одном RecyclerView. Вам просто нужно в адаптере возвращать суммарное количество элементов и заголовков, переопределить метод `getItemViewType`, в котором возвращать тип элемента по позиции (у вас это видимо: заголовок, список1, список2 или список3). Под каждый тип элемента сделать отдельный ViewHolder и в методах `onBindViewHolder` и `onCreateViewHolder` создавать разные лайауты и по разному их наполнять в зависимости от их типа. Пример сходу смог найти только [такой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/470214/197641).

Comment: Да, это решение выглядит более красивым и логичным, чем моё предположение. Только у меня 3 заголовка и 3 списка, но это не меняет сути. Благодарю за совет.

Answer (score 4):

1. Возьмите `LinearLayout` c вертикальной ориентацией и высотой в экран.
2. Поместите в него `TextView` и `RecyclerView` в нужном кол-ве.
3. Добейтесь нужного размещения последних на экране устанавливая им высоту через вес. Если будете устанавливать высоту в `dp` или `WRAP_CONTENT`, то на некоторых экранах просто всё не поместится. С другой стороны, при использовании веса на маленьких экранах всё будет очень мелко. Так что я бы на вашем месте так бы не делал, а выводил бы списке в отдельном фрагменте/диалоге вместо помещения их всех на один экран.

Comment: я вместо LinearLayout использую RelativeLayout, мне кажется, так легче и правильнее располагать элементы. А как быть с LayoutManager и Адаптерами для RecyclerView? Для каждого создавать новый адаптер ?

Comment: Может есть смысл использовать ScrollView, как контейнер для всех элементов?

Comment: @Denis422, Relative тут точно не нужен, плюс он прожорливее по ресурсам. Да, менеджеры и адаптеры должн быть свои для каждого списка. ScrollView использовать нельзя - будет конфликт и его без **АЦЦЦКИХ** костылей не обойти. Если очень надо - то сделайте лучше один список с разным типом элементов. То, что вы хотите сделать либо неправильно, либо некрасиво, либо невозможно без костылей.

Comment: ScrollView уже попробовал и разочаровался) Я добавил еще одну картинку, чтобы было понятнее что я хочу. Всё таки один список с разными холдерами наверно лучше будет..

Comment: Да, один список-лучшее решение