# Помогите с условием android вывести значение из класса

Tags: java, android

имеется адаптер RecyclerView с условием. Хочу сделать чтобы при определенном значении полученных данных из List менялся LayoutInflater,
Вот код условия

```
* String TypeID= rTypeID;

 @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
          *  if (position == TypeID.equals("2"))return TITEM1;
            return TTEM2;
        }



       @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

            holder.rTypeID = notes.get(position).getTypeID();


            switch (type) {
                case TITEM1:
                    //для итем1

                    break;
                case TITEM2:
                    //для итем2

                    break;
            }

        }        

        }

        public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public final View mView;
           * public String rTypeID;

            public ViewHolder(View v) {
                super(v);
                mView = v;

            }
        }
```

Помогите пожалуйста все никак не могу понять, где проблемма указал *
помогите что мне сюда писать (в этом коде неправильно) я незнаю что юда писать  -->

```
 if (position == TypeID.equals("2"))return TITEM1;
                return TTEM2;
```

Comment: А зачем два метода `getItemViewType()` и для чего `typeID` типа `String`, если хранит число?

Comment: @pavlofff, ошибся когда сюда писал 2 метода, typeID почему стринг, потому что я получаю лист и позиция `holder.rTypeID = notes.get(position).getTypeID();` получает стринг а не число/ исправил выше

Comment: Я вижу, что он получает.  Зачем вы используете для числа тип `String`, а не `int`, к примеру. И что должно делать условие

Comment: @pavlofff, вот я делаю по этому примеру [ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/470209/) условие должно быть ---> если позиция итема(getTypeID) = 2 то меняется ресурс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете тип `String`, который предназначен для хранения строковых переменных, чтобы хранить число. Затем вы пытаетесь сравнить разные типы - числовой `int` и строковый `String`, хотя даже для этого сравнения условие составлено неверно и конкретно в вашем сравнении вы сравниваете `int` (позицию) и результат сравнения строки с символом "2", что вернет `boolean`.
Хотя Java и имеет возможности к приведению строкового типа к числу, ваш подход изначально неверен, вам нужно хранить число в числовом типе изначально.

Далее, здесь в вашей задаче очевидное логическое противоречие - позиция айтема в списке и значение в поле TypeID - это два разных параметра.
Если вам нужна другая разметка для айтемов с полем в модели TypeID = 2, то и проверять нужно это условие, а не сравнивать с текущей позицией:

```
int TypeID = rTypeID;

 @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            if (TypeID == 2 ) return TITEM1;
            return TTEM2;
        }
```

если же вам нужна другая разметка для второй позиции списка, то проверять нужно позицию, а не какое то поле в модели:

```
 @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position == 2) return TITEM1;
        return TTEM2;
    }
```

PS: писать "не могу понять где проблема" немного странно для программиста, потому что при ошибке выдается лог - стэктрейс, где указано в чем именно проблема - его надо прочитать и решать, как исправить.
Прежде чем продолжить программировать, рекомендую почитать какой то учебник по Java, с таким "багажом знаний" вы много все равно не напрограммируете, а копипастом чужих решений из интернета, не понимая языка, на котором пишите, еще никто программу не написал.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, но учится на примерах разве плохо ? просто я с оператор if не сталкивался еще. Этот форум для вопросов и ответов вроде как, просто не все учатся на программистов и мое окружение даже в винду не знают, а читать маны по java ну этим точно интерес не создашь(особенно когда обсудить некем), а писать программку которую хочешь и учится ну это куда лучше, да кстати я скоро закончу возможно вы не правы )

Comment: @Артем Примеры это не плохо, а только язык нужно знать - синтаксис, конструкции, правила и тп., чтобы по два дня не находится в тупике и ждать помощи неизвестно сколько из-за несоответствия типов, да и вообще понимать, что в примере происходит и как переделать под свою задачу без посторонней помощи.

Comment: а не подскажете как мне теперь вывести значение из `class ViewHolder` а то горит красным `int TypeID = rTypeID;`

Comment: @Артем то, что горит красным это плохо - что то не так. Однако мой уровень ясновидения еще не достиг такой силы, чтобы по цвету определять в чем там у вас проблема. IDE дает подсказку для всех ошибок, отмеченных красным - ее надо прочитать и исправить.

Comment: ,ну яже написал что `TypeID` не видит ` rTypeID` из под `class ViewHolder`