# ExpandableListView в прокручивающемся экране. (Android)

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо реализовать такую верстку. Основная проблема, что все в один экран не вмещается и приходится использовать ScrollView. А ListView и Scroll противопоказаны друг другу. 
Как выйти из такой ситуации?

Comment: Попробуйте CoorinatorLayout - вроде, то что нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Просто засуньте всё что скролится в список (и возможно стоит уже переходить на RecyclerView вместо ListView) и избавьтесь от ScrollView. Как сделать несколько разных типов строк для RecyclerView можно посмотреть например [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/470214/197641) или [тут (на английском)](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView).