# Прокрутка элемента Layout, затем прокрутка RecyclerView

Tags: android

Есть фрагмент с `ViewPager`, состоящий их трех страниц. В каждой странице `RecyclerView`. Выше `ViewPager` блок с информацией. Как сделать так, что бы сначала прокрутился блок с информацией, а затем срабатывала прокрутка в `RecyclerView`? Его нельзя поместить первым элементов в `RecyclerView`, т.к. он общий для всех страниц в `ViewPager`.

```
<LinearLayout
   ...>

   <!-- вот этот блок нужно прокрутить перед RecyclerView, которые во ViewPager -->
   <FrameLayout
      ...>
      ...
   </FrameLayout>

   <ViewPager 
      .../>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Если вам нужно что то вроде хедера в списке, поместите свой блок с информацией в сам `RecyclerView` [таким способом](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/470214/177345) - это самое простое решение. Или подробнее опишите, какого именно взаимодействия вы хотите добиться.

Comment: Нельзя помещать в RecyclerView, т.к. это общий блок для трех страниц в ViewPager.

Comment: TabLayout имеется? размер ViewPager фиксированный для всех экранов?

Comment: Может имеет смысл поместить Ваш `FrameLayout` в `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

Answer (score 1):

Оберните все в `NestedScrollView`.....

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <!--ваш контент-->
            </RelativeLayout>

                <!--укажите имя вашего пакета до кастомного пейджера-->
            <yuo.package.ExViewPager
                android:id="@+id/view_pager_recommendation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Что бы `ViewPager` был нормального размера после создания укажите хардкодом размер, а если динамически то унаследуйтесь от оригинала и переопределите метод `onMeasure`

```
public class ExViewPager extends ViewPager {
    public ExViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int height = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            int h = child.getMeasuredHeight();
            if (h > height) height = h;
        }
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

Есть баг, когда при касании `RecyclerView` теряется  `"инерция"` прокрутки, для избавления сия перепоределите 2 метода у `LayoutManager`

```
 GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false){
            @Override
            public boolean canScrollVertically() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean canScrollHorizontally() {
                return false;
            }
        };
```

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы сначала срабатывала прокрутка блока,  а затем прокрутка списка. В этом примере сначала нужно до конца долистать список, затем только прокрутится блок.