# Подскажите как сделать такой ListView?

Tags: android, listview, adapter, android-customview

Беру данные с апишки. Как мне вывести ListView через один? я думал все в один адаптер, а потом брать 2 разных item и в 2 разные адаптеры.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это обычный listview (или recicedView). Просто для вьюшек есть два разных layout. И в зависимости от индекса, показывается либо тот, либо другой.

Comment: так мне нужно список выводить один слева один справа...и т.д....как-то через один сделать

Comment: просто в getView смотреть текущий индекс и делать условие `if (index % 2 == 0) ....`

Comment: Насколько я вижу, это один список. Просто половина элемента списка - это картинка

Comment: можно использовать  RecyclerView с  layout manager  StaggeredGridLayoutManager

Comment: Это один список, просто картинка то слева, то справа. Для реализации такого списка нужно [переопределить метод](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/470214/177345) `getItemViewType()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно создать 1 адаптер и 2 layout с разметкой:
1)левая картинка и текст "one_item_layout"
2)текст и правая картинка "two_item_layout"

Вот держите метод из адаптера (переделанный под вас), замените его.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if ( (position & 1) == 0 ) {
        //Вставляем лейаут с картинкой слева (если парное число position)
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.one_item_layout, parent, false);
    } 
    else {
        //Вставляем лейаут с картинкой справа (если не парное число position)
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.two_item_layout, parent, false);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: наверное, самое худшее решение, которое работает. Про recycling можно забыть. Это всеравно, что напихать все View сразу в `ScrollView`