# Вывод в RecyclerView нужных мне item

Tags: android, recyclerview

Подскажите пожалуйста. Можно ли сделать вывод в `RecyclerView` нужных мне `item`.
Я так понимаю, что нужно переопределить метод `getItemViewType()`, и по позиции нужного `item` в `onCreateViewHolder()`, скрывать `view` - `view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`
Если я верно мыслю, то не понятно, как в `getItemViewType()` задать условие.
Получается, что я должен в `onBindViewHolder()`, создать какой-то локальный массив, в который записать нужные мне `int position`.
А потом в методе `getItemViewType()`, пробегать поэтому массиву и при совпадении указывать `int viewType` для `onCreateViewHolder()`.
Вот здесь смотрел [Как использовать несколько `view` в `recyclerview`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/470209/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-view-%D0%B2-recyclerview)

Comment: Скорее всего вам нужно просто передавать в адаптер только те данные, которые нужны для отображения, а не в самом адаптере что то скрывать. То есть, сначала подготовить список с данными только для нужных айтемов, потом передавать его в RecyclerView. То, что вы пытаетесь использовать - для **отображения** айтемов разного вида, а не скрытия их. К тому же в методах адаптера не надо "пробегать" ни по каким массивам, они сами пробегают по ним.

Comment: Знаете, я тоже склоняюсь к этому же.