# Группировка элементов в TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Имеется `List` объектов:

```
Группа 1 | Имя 1 | Значение
Группа 1 | Имя 2 | Значение
Группа 2 | Имя 3 | Значение
```

Этот список я вывожу в TableLayout, кроме имени группы. В разметке я создал Table Layout, и затем в коде заполняю TableRow

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="60dp">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/attrib_name"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.6"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/min"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"/></TableRow>
```

Этим методом я заполняю строки TableRow

```
public void FillTable()
{
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.attrib_table);

    for(int i=0;i<myData.size();i++)
    {
        TableRow row = (TableRow) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.attrib_row, null);
        ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.attrib_name)).setText(myData.get(i).getToroParameterMeasurement());
        ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.min)).setText(myData.get(i).getMinNominal()); 

 table.addView(row);        }    }
```

Мне надо, чтобы все выводимые значения в TableLayout группировались по имени группы и выводились подобным образом:

```
Группа 1
Имя 1 | Значение
Имя 2 | Значение
Группа 2
Имя 3 | Значение
```

Можно ли настроить TableLayout на вывод данных таким форматом? Если нет, с помощью чего можно так выводить данные на экран?

Comment: Для этих целей используются списки. Есть уже [готовые решения](https://github.com/search?utf8=✓&q=sectioned+recyclerview&type=) или можно [сделать самому](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/470214/177345).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вот прямо нужен именно `TableLayout`, то надо использовать 2 разные версии `TableRow` - одна такая как вы расписали, а вторая что-то типа такого:

```
<TableRow
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="60dp">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/group"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"/>
</TableRow>
```

которую надо инфлейтить в строках с группировкой

Answer (score 3):

TableLayout не подойдет, и вообще он deprecated, никогда его не используй. А используй лучше `RecyclerView` с двумя вьюхолдерами. Один вьюхолдер для названия группы (Группа 1, Группа 2..), а второй для, собственно, строки, отображающей твои объекты

Comment: `TableLayout` не deprecated. Это нормальный компонент, который не требует адаптера. Всё зависит от ситуации, использовать его можно и иногда полезно.