# RecyclerView - сделать группировку списка

Tags: android, recyclerview

Всем привет. Имеются данные в базе такого вида:

```
 _id | category | name
  1  |   cat1   | name2
  2  |   cat1   | name5
  3  |   cat3   | name1
  4  |   cat2   | name4
  5  |   cat1   | name3
  6  |   cat3   | name6
  7  |   cat1   | name9
```

Необходимо вывести эти данные в список через RecyclerView в таком виде:

```
  cat1
  1  | name2
  2  | name5
  5  | name3
  7  | name9
  cat2
  4  | name4
  cat3
  3  | name1
  6  | name6
```

Другими словами, необходимо из поля **category** создать своеобразный заголовок (разделитель/группу) в списке, а после каждого заголовка вывести данные, которые соответствуют этому заголовку.

**Мой код фрагмента:**

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.DividerItemDecoration;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Tab1 extends Fragment
    {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    DB_Helper databaseHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor userCursor;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_tab1, container, false);

        databaseHelper = new DB_Helper(getContext());
        db = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        userCursor =  db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM `" + DB_Helper.DATABASE_TABLE + "` WHERE `_id` > '0' ORDER BY `category` ASC, `_id` DESC", null);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myData = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<String, String> mTab1;
        if (userCursor.moveToFirst())
            {
            do {
               mTab1 = new HashMap<>();
               mTab1.put("id", userCursor.getString(userCursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Helper.ID)));
               mTab1.put("cate", userCursor.getString(userCursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Helper.CATEGORY)));
               mTab1.put("name", userCursor.getString(userCursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Helper.NAME)));
               myData.add(mTab1);
               }
            while (userCursor.moveToNext());
            }

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

        // если вы уверены, что изменения в контенте не изменят размер лайота, то передаём параметр true - это увеличивает производительность
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // используем LinearLayoutManager для отображения как ListView
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        // добавляет горизонтальные полосочки между пунктами
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(mRecyclerView.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

        // создаём адаптер
        mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(myData);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        return rootView;
        }
    }
```

**Мой код адаптера RecyclerView:**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>
    {
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mDataset;

    public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataset)
        {
        mDataset = dataset;
        }

    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_tab1_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
        }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
        HashMap<String, String> fast_parse = mDataset.get(position);
        String cate_str = fast_parse.get("cate");
        String name_str = fast_parse.get("name");

        holder.mMyListCateView.setText(cate_str);
        holder.mMyListNameView.setText(name_str);
        }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
        {
        return mDataset.size();
        }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
        {
        private TextView mMyListCateView, mMyListNameView;
        private LinearLayout holderLayout;

        public ViewHolder(View v)
            {
            super(v);
            mMyListCateView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.myMyCate);
            mMyListNameView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.myMyName);
            holderLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);
            holderLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
            }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
            {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION)
                {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Squares_Dynamic_Base.class);
                HashMap<String, String> fast_parse = mDataset.get(position);
                intent.putExtra("id", fast_parse.get("id"));
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Из примеров [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/649013/) и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/470209/) я понял, что необходимо использовать getItemViewType и с его помощью подгружать разные Layout для заголовка пунктов и для самих пунктов (это идеальный вариант, т.к. по идее оформление заголовка будет отличаться от оформления пунктов списка). Но во множестве других примеров используют списки, в которых уже изначально добавлены данные для заголовков, а у меня заголовки должны сформироваться из того, что есть. Прошу подсказать кодом как реализовать желаемое.

P.S. Различные украшательства и красивые эффекты НЕ нужные. Нужен максимально простой и рабочий код.

Answer (score 2):

Вот есть  библиотека, там у них и есть пример с исходниками

[RecyclerView](https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter)

метод генерирование items. Как видите у меня они разные есть. У меня допустим
 `HeaderModel_Cvodka` и `ContentModel_Cvodka`.

```
@NonNull
    private ArrayList<ItemModel> getItems() {
        final ArrayList<ItemModel> items = new ArrayList<>();

        DannieClanNew dannieClan;
        if(locationTanki.getDannieClanNew() != null)
             dannieClan = locationTanki.getDannieClanNew();
        else
            dannieClan = null;

        items.add(new HeaderModel_Cvodka(Integer.toString(locationTanki.getPersonaly_dannie().getGlobal_rating()), "Личный рейтинг", "Изображение", locationTanki.getPersonaly_dannie().getNickname(), dannieClan));
        // for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        //
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            items.add(new ContentModel_Cvodka(TITLES2.get(j),TITLES2_1[j],IMAGES2[j]));
            //    }
        }
}`
```

В примере вы увидите такую строчку `mRecyclerViewAdapter.setItems(getItems());` там где объявлен `RececlerView`

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Я пересмотрел множество примеров и библиотек. Все они для меня слишком крутые. Хотелось бы что-то очень простое, чтобы просто отображался список без сворачиваний групп, без различных эффектов. Вот просто заголовок и пункты...

Comment: почему бы вам не использовать тогда обычный RecyclerView с двумя объектами. И просто в зависимости от какого тот выводите. Сейчас посмотрю у меня вроде есть пример

Comment: посмотрите, пожалуйста. Я в программировании андроидов неопытен, поэтому аналогичные примеры мне очень помогли бы.

Comment: https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter,  у него есть пример. Пока смотрите тут, а я пока свой найду, как у себя использую

Comment: попробуйте разобрать этот пример. У меня слишком большой и сложный пример

Comment: Попробую разобрать данный пример. Можете пока на словах объяснить как работать с двумя объектами? Я так понимаю в файле фрагмента у меня сейчас создан только один объект. Мне его нужно разбить на два: один с заголовками, а другой с пунктами и потом передать эти два объекта в RecyclerView?

Comment: да, вам нужно 2.  Выложил ту часть которая отвечает за выбор какой элемент отображать. У вас понятное дело по другому принципу будет. Посмотрите в примере папку items. Там как раз лежит три объекта (Category, Header, Content).

Answer (score 1):

Для создания элементов разного вида нужно просто использовать разные `ViewHolder` , никто же не запрещает делать их разного вида, более того есть метод `getItemViewType()`, type задаётся константами int. При таком раскладе хранить данные можно в `TreeMap<Key,List<YourItem>>` или `SparseArray`(что для платформы Android предпочтительней), в этом случае метод getItemCount() должен возвращать сумму размеров всех листов + 1 хедер на каждый лист, а в методе `getItemViewType()` нужно написать логику подсчёта типа элемента(чтобы отловить момент когда нужно вернуть тип хедера). Ну вот собственно и всё.

Comment: У меня опыт совсем небольшой. Я как бы логику примерно понимаю. Но я не знаю как это реализовать на практике. Грубо говоря сейчас делаю методом тыка и из примеров в интернете, пытаюсь слепить всё в единое. Если вам не трудно, вы не могли бы показать что куда в коде вставлять? Мне кажется это не совсем сложно, тем более мне не требуется различного рода эффекты.

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое и топорное решение на мой взгляд

Сверху в разметку элемента добавляешь разделитель, в нем например будет только TextView

В адаптере проверяешь, если предыдущий элемент отличается по категории от текущего, то показываешь разделитель, иначе скрываешь его

Это будет самый простой вариант

Немного года

Разметка элемента списка

```
LinearLayout orientation: vertical
    TextView id: category
    TextView id: name
```

В самом адаптере в методе где у тебя происходит вывод информации в ViewHolder примерно такой код

```
viewHolder.category.setText(list.get(position).category)
if (position == 0 || !list.get(position).category.equals(list.get(position-1)) {
    viewHolder.category.setVisibility(VISIBLE)
} else {
    viewHolder.category.setVisibility(GONE)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем посидел, подумал как можно реализовать необходимое и пришёл к такому решению. В первом файле просто взял кусок:

```
mTab1 = new HashMap<>();
mTab1.put("id", userCursor.getString(userCursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Helper.ID)));
mTab1.put("cate", userCursor.getString(userCursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Helper.CATEGORY)));
mTab1.put("name", userCursor.getString(userCursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Helper.NAME)));
myData.add(mTab1);
```

и заменил его на это:

```
TYPE_CATE = userCursor.getString(userCursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Helper.CATEGORY));
if (TYPE_CATE.equals(TYPE_NEW))
    {
    mTab1.put("id", userCursor.getString(userCursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Helper.ID)));
    mTab1.put("cate", userCursor.getString(userCursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Helper.CATEGORY)));
    mTab1.put("name", userCursor.getString(userCursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Helper.NAME)));
    mTab1.put("rang", "0");
    }
else
    {
    mTab1.put("cate", userCursor.getString(userCursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Helper.CATEGORY)));
    mTab1.put("rang", "1");
    TYPE_NEW = userCursor.getString(userCursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Helper.CATEGORY));
    userCursor.moveToPrevious();
    }
```

при этом там, где определяем переменные нужно дописать:

```
public String TYPE_CATE = "";
public String TYPE_NEW = "";
```

Таким образом сформировался список именно в том виде, в котором нужен был. Т.е. одна строка с заголовком и пометка, что это именно заголовок. И далее все пункты, которые соответствуют этому заголовку и т.д.

Затем данные передаются в адаптер, который я легко и просто переписал согласно [этому](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PTnXzCCc4MA) видео (смотреть примерно с 6-ой минуты).

Не знаю конечно насколько это правильно. Возможно реализация очень кривая и логически не правильная, но результат работы радует. Всё работает именно как надо ))