# Как программно в LinearLayout(Vertical) разместить по правому/левому краю textView?

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Имеется LinearLayout(Vertical), в ней находятся элементы, среди которых есть TextView.Его  ширина равна WrapContent.
Нужно чтобы textView в зависимости от условий размещался либо по правому краю, либо по левому.
В xml я бы просто использовал бы layout_gravity:RIGHT/LEFT.
А вот в коде не знаю, подскажите пожалуйста.

разметка xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical">    

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:paddingRight="25dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Самый обычный текст" />

</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:text="time" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Если вы делаете какой то чат, то это все не так делается (в вашей задумке он в итоге упадет по OoME после n-го сообщения), а через `RecyclerView` (`ListView`) и [переопределение метода `getItemViewType()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/470214/177345) адаптера, для вывода каждого сообщения с нужной стороны. Можете посмотреть примеры на github, [например ChatKit](https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/ChatKit), можете даже его (или анолгичные библиотеки) использовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно установить лейаут параметры той вью, которую вы размещаете:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.START;  // Gravity.END, Gravity.LEFT, Gravity.RIGHT

textView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: что то не работает, выдает ошибку    " java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams"

Comment: Вы точно размещаете текст вью внутри `LinearLayout`? Или может внутри `RelativeLayout`? Покажите вашу xml разметку.

Comment: добавил в первом посту разметку

Comment: отбой, нашел собственный косяк.