# Вариативность действий в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter, recyclerviewadapter

Хотел бы немного посоветоваться со знающими людьми. Можно ли используя `Adapter` делать проверку на то, есть ли данные в массиве. И в зависимости от этого уже делать другое действие или создавать другой ViewHolder(что мне более нужно сейчас).

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Adapter.VH p1, int p2)
{
    if(data[p2]!=null){
    String Text = data[p2];
    p1.Txt.setText(Text);
    }else{
        MA.Empty();//MainActivity
    }
}
```

Данный способ не работает, как его можно изменить чтобы работал?

*P.S.Если необходимо, то дополню вопрос.*

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте!

Создайте свои константы, которые будут соответствовать разным типам.

```
private final static String VIEW_TYPE_TEXT = "text";
private final static String VIEW_TYPE_IMAGE = "image";
```

После чего в вашем Adapter(е) переопределите метод `getItemViewType(int position)` - этот метод будет брать элемент из вашего списка по позиции, проверять к какому типу он относится и возвращаться int значение.

```
@Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            switch (dataTypes.get(position)){
                case VIEW_TYPE_TEXT:
                    return 0;
                case VIEW_TYPE_IMAGE:
                    return 1;
            }
        }
```

Дальше все просто. В методе `onCreateViewHolder`есть параметр `viewType`смотрите чему он равен и создаете ваш ViewHolder. *Здесь на самом деле лучше использовать константы для типов item.*

```
@NonNull
        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v;
            switch (viewType){
                case 0:
                {
                    view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_data_text, parent, false);
                    return new DataViewHolder(view);
                }
                case 1:
                {
                    view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_data_image, parent, false);
                    return new DataViewHolder(view);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

В методе `onBindViewHolder` вам нужно будет привести ваш `ViewHolder` к нужному типу и передать нужные вам данные из вашей коллекции.

Код целиком:

```
public class TestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    private final static String VIEW_TYPE_TEXT = "text";
    private final static String VIEW_TYPE_IMAGE = "image";

    private List<String> dataTypes;

    public TestAdapter(List<String> dataTypes){
        this.dataTypes = dataTypes;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v;
        switch (viewType){
            case 0:
            {
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_data_text, parent, false);
                return new DataViewHolder(view);
            }
            case 1:
            {
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_data_image, parent, false);
                return new DataViewHolder(view);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        switch (holder.getItemViewType()){
            case 0:{
                String data = dataTypes.get(position);
                TextViewHolder textViewHolder = (TextViewHolder) holder;
                textViewHolder.bind(data);
            }
            case 1:{
                String data = dataTypes.get(position);
                ImageViewHolder imageViewHolder = (ImageViewHolder) holder;
                imageViewHolder.bind(data);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataTypes.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        switch (dataTypes.get(position)){
            case VIEW_TYPE_TEXT:
                return 0;
            case VIEW_TYPE_IMAGE:
                return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Надеюсь вам это поможет, если будут вопросы - спрашивайте.

p.s. обновлен в соотвествии с замечанием @pavloff.

Comment: пример никак не объясняет, как это должно работать. Это [ответ объясняет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/470214/177345), как это работает

Comment: @pavloff так получше?

Comment: Конечно спасибо вам большое, однако я интересовался немного другой темой. Можно ли делать проверку есть ли данные в массиве на определенном месте data[p2], и уже в зависимости от этого делать что-то

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под "определенном месте". У вас есть 10 чисел, если одно из них подходит по какому либо условию вы даете ему отличный от остальных тип и делаете с ним что хотите.. Можете брать позицию проверять что позиция равна 3 присвоить отличный от остальных тип и делать с ним что хотите.

Comment: Я имею ввиду то, что, допустим, в массиве под индексом 12 ничего нет, а при этом приложение вылетает (если пытается создать продолжение RV). Я же хочу делать проверку на наличие данных в данной позиции и уже в зависимости от этого делать какое-либо другое действие.