# RecyclerView Android

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Есть RecyclerView который выводит пубикации загруженные из сервера. Так вот среди публикаций есть ВИП публикации у которых Вью оссобенное. Проблема была такая что например загрузил 16 публикаций из них последняя вип скажем. В таком случае если не скролить все ок но после того как до скролишь до конца и назад в начала то первая тоже начинает показывать как вип хоть оно и стандартная публикация. Что за фигня подумал я и начал капаться в методах RecyclerView связанах с кешью и сделал вот это:

```
 recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(1000);
```

После этого норма работает. Конечно не пробовал загружать больше 20 публикаций. Что я сделал? Что изменил не знаете ли вы?

Comment: Покажите код адаптера

Comment: Вы сказали адаптеру создавать новые вью для первой 1000 элементов и только потом их переиспользовать. В этом ответе показано как сделать адаптер на два вида вью: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/470214/11515

Comment: @woesss спасибо очень помогло