# Параметр viewType в onCreateViewHolder (RecyclerView)

Tags: android, recyclerview

Хочу сделать универсальную реализацию RecyclerView для разных типов View.

Для этого нужно определять тип вьюхи, которую надо отрисовать в данный момент. 
Откуда берется параметр `viewType` в этом методе и какие значения он может принимать?

```
 @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
```

Comment: он задается в адаптере при создании ViewHoldera. гуглите сначала примеры на английском, потом спрашивайте. Этот вопрос дублируется многократно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Параметр `viewType` в метод `onCreateViewHolder()` возвращает переопределенный метод адаптера `getItemViewType()`. В этом методе вы должны организовать логику определения типа айтема по позиции в списке (входной аргумент метода).
 Если метод не переопределен в адаптере, то параметр возвращает 0 для всех позиций.

Параметр может быть любым целым числом типа `int`, конкретное значение вы указываете сами в логике метода. Число это служит только для идентификации типа айтема.

[Пример использования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/470209/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-view-%d0%b2-recyclerview)