# Kotlin изменить tools:listitem в RecyclerView по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: android, kotlin

Мне нужно по нажатию на кнопку изменить tools:listitem на note_rv_item_2.xml в RecyclerView в моем основном activity. Как я могу это сделать в коде и могу ли вообще?

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainRL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/theme2"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/notesRV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="618dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/addBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        tools:listitem="@layout/note_rv_item_1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

note_rv_item_1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/grey"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/idTVNote"
            android:layout_width="381dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/idIVDelete"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/idIVStar"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="11dp"
            android:text="Note"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/idIVDelete"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/delete" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/idIVStar"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="350dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:button="@drawable/check_box"
            android:buttonTint="@color/white"
            android:padding="3dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Вот сюда мне нужно вписать изменение параметра tools:listitem на note_rv_item_2.xml в моём MainActivity.kt, но я не знаю как это сделать и решения в интернете не нашёл.

```
themeBtn.setOnClickListener {

}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @Духсообщества внизу вопроса дополнил

Comment: Параметры с префиксом `tools:` предназначены исключительно для предпросмотра в студии, они никак не влияют на работу приложения на устройстве. Поэтому сформулируйте в вопросе чего вы хотите этим добиться. Разметку элемента списка вы задаёте в адаптере, там же её и нужно менять.

Comment: @woesss как это сделать в адаптере? Я просто новичок в этом. Мне нужно заменить файл отображения  listitem(ну или как-то по другому, если это невозможно) по нажатию кнопки.

Comment: Для всех элементов разом или того, который кликнули? Возможное решение здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/470214/11515

Comment: Для RecyclerView заменить note_rv_item_1.xml на другой файл note_rv_item_2.xml в listitem. Данные в RecyclerView подгружаются с базы данных и все элементы будут одинаковые