# Использование внешнего ViewBinding в ViewHolder (Android)

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-viewpager

Хочется возможно странного: организовать перелистывание статических страниц (отдельные файлы разметки) с помощью ViewPager2, без создания фрагментов. Что-то вроде этого:

```
class ModbusPageAdapter(private val binding: ViewBinding, private val pages: List<ViewBinding>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ModbusPageAdapter.ModbusPageHolder>() {

var prevPosition: Int = 0
class ModbusPageHolder(binding: ViewBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ModbusPageHolder {
    return ModbusPageHolder(binding)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return pages.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ModbusPageHolder, position: Int) {
    val page = pages[position]

    pages[prevPosition].root.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    page.root.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    prevPosition = position

}
```

}

Т.е. в основном коде создаю основной binding для "контейнера" и список binding-ов для страниц, их передаю в адаптер viewpager-а. Однако это не работает, т.к. holder выбрасывает исключение "ViewHolder views must not be attached when created".
Если внутри адаптера использовать не binding, а "надувать" из R.layout, то естественно, объекты внутри viewpager-а и в основном коде будут разными.
Так вот: как их всех подружить?

Comment: это какой-то новый уровень извращения. для начала, почитайте про жизненный цикл Фрагментов и как они работают

Comment: А причем здесь фрагменты? Из описания на ViewPager2:
Display Views OR Fragments in a swipeable format. Я ж написал, что хочу без создания фрагментов. Не получится?

Comment: Я так и не понял что вы хотите сделать. Ошибка говорит что вы пытаетесь отобразить вью из одного объекта биндинга более одного раза. А происходит это потому что в каждый холдер вы отдаёте биндинг контейнера вместо биндинга элемента.

Comment: Ну вот есть у меня несколько xml с разным содержанием. Их надо свайпить в одном экране, но при этом не создавая фрагмент на каждую разметку. В активити должен иметься биндинг к каждому из этих экранов для организации интерфейса с пользователем.

Comment: Вы отдаёте биндинг контейнера во все холдеры, а должны в каждый холдер свой биндинг из списка `pages`. Какую-то сомнительную архитектуру вы реализуете. Но если на то пошло - задействуйте механизм viewType: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/470214/11515

Comment: Спасибо! Понял свою ошибку: не вкурил, что холдер в адаптере не один ))

Answer (score 0):

Благодаря мастеру *woesss* удалось разобраться.

Финальный вариант:

```
class SlidePageAdapter(private val pages: List<ViewBinding>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<SlidePageAdapter.SlidePageHolder>() {

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return position
    }
    class SlidePageHolder(binding: ViewBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SlidePageHolder {
        return SlidePageHolder(pages[viewType])
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return pages.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SlidePageHolder, position: Int) {
    }
}
```

Можно передать список из любого количества биндингов на вьюхи, все работает и не выглядит извращением! *Woesss*, большое спасибо!